# How to uninstall netbeans IDE by unconventional means?

Tags: uninstall, 19.04, netbeans

I installed Netbeans IDE some time ago (on Ubuntu 19.04) and don't remember the exact method I used to do so. I'm sure it wasn't using `apt install` because running `sudo apt remove netbeans` returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'netbeans' is not installed, so not removed
```

In the Software Center there's no "uninstall" option as well.

Running `locate netbeans` I found what seems to be netbeans installation folder in `/opt/netbeans`, but there's no `uninstal.sh` file there.

All the questions I found with similar titles pointed to uninstall netbeans using the `uninstall.sh` file, the Software Center or the `sudo apt remove netbeans` command, but none of these solutions are working.

Comment: Run `netbeans --version` and just say if it returns version or error

Comment: Also check if `uninstall.sh` is stored in `/usr/local/netbeans-x.x`.

Comment: running  `netbeans --version` returns: `Product Version         = Apache NetBeans IDE 11.0`  and launches the IDE

Comment: there's no other netbeans folder elsewhere in the system

Comment: OK,this may sound strange,but try to install neatbens(again) and then uninstall it ( with `apt-get remove --purge neatbeans` or with `uninstall.sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So
If you can not uninstall any app of package via terminal, or through Store(Software, Discover etc.) or `uninstall.sh` is missing, then you need to install it again. No matters if it is terminal way, installer(.sh or .run) or Store. Then uninstall it (based on way how you install it again), but `sudo apt-get remove --purge <package name> && sudo apt-get autoremove`(package name is `netbeans` in this case)  is fine in most of cases. Now app should be completly removed. This error is pretty often, becaose if you are using any app for cleaning, that apps can often remove `uninstall.sh` or sometimes system can not find that app with`sudo apt-get remove`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the Netbeans installed through the Debian package is obtained as follows:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove --purge apache-netbeans
```

From [Here](https://itslinuxfoss.com/install-netbeans-ubuntu-22-04/)